# How does SSR works after the initial load in NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

In pure VueJS application we have a `<div id="app"></div>` container, where VueJS puts all the stuff which needs to be rendered.

Thus, if we open the source code in browser, we will not see any rendered content.

So, if we use Nuxt capabilities of SSR, on the first initial load all the components are rendered on the server, ad we see some HTML stuff.

But, what happens when we navigate through the site, when it works in "spa mode" (using `<nuxt-link>`). When I click on a link, the site is not fully reloaded. I cannot see any requests in chrome dev tools, non XHR non others. And even if we got fully rendered content from the backend, it is being inserted through javascript, like in `<div id="app"></div>"` case, since we do not reload the page.

But I can see in the source code that everything works as SEO needs: all the html is present in source code after navigation to some other routes. But how this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is called Hydration.

Note that in SPA mode everthing gets rendered on the client. When using SSR the first render happens on the server, therefore you can see the HTML in the source code.

Once on the client, VueJS will "hydrate" it's state, meaning that it will set the App's state to what came from the server. If you then use `<nuxt-link>` it will navigate in SPA mode. On the other hand, using a normal `<a>` won't.

This is perfect for all use cases, as Google and other search engines don't have Javascript enabled they will just do a completely new request to all your links, but your users will have the feeling of an SPA page.

Comment: pretty sure google robot has some sort of javascript enabled

Comment: That might be true, but it surely does not follow <nuxt-link> tags as a normal user. Let me check about that

Comment: https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/122/does-google-execute-javascript

Looks like it does but it's not really guaranteed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you clarify, this is what I couldn't understand: when I navigate through nuxt-link, nuxt app "hydrates" for example some kind of <div>. But it's done purely through ajax. I'm talking about when it becomes "spa" mode. So why I am able to see html content (if I check the source code of the page through browser) in nuxt js app (when it already turned in spa, after the initial load), and I can't do the same with vuejs? They are both in spa mode after initial load, when I traveling by using router/nuxt link

Comment: Also I couldn't get it why I can't see any requests to the server in chrome developer tools, when navigating thought nuxt-link. It should somehow get this pre-rendered data from the server after all :)

Comment: When you press Ctrl+U to see the source code Chrome fetches the current URL again

Comment: Nope, when you change the page all needed JS has already been downloaded, so no need to fetch from the server. Nuxt fetches all chunks of JavaScript with the first load